# Simple maths game

Tags: java, android, math

I've tried a few solutions, but not having much luck. If anyone with some spare time can have a look at my code and maybe point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Here I have a button that's calling these methods. One to check the answer and one to get another question which will display in the textview. Ideally I want a sequence of ten random questions and for the user to be able to guess each one via the edittext and if they get one right a score counter is incremented each time.

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.keypad_hash:

    checkAnswer(editTextEquation.getText().toString(), editText.getText().toString());

    editTextEquation.setText(getQuestion());

    break;
```

I'm having difficulty working out how to code the rest

```
 String getQuestion(){

    random1 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    random2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

    if(i1 == 1){
    question = String.valueOf(random1 + "+" + random2);

    }
    if(i1 == 2){
    question = String.valueOf(random1 + "-" +random2);


    }
    if(i1 == 3){
    question = String.valueOf(random1 + "/" +random2);


    }
    if(i1 == 4){
    question = String.valueOf(random1 + "*" +random2);


    }

    return question;

}

boolean checkAnswer(String question, String answer){


    return true;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add something like

```
double correctAnswer;
(...)
if(i1 == 4){
    question = String.valueOf(random1 + "*" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1*random2
}
```

Comment: Yeah I had something like that before, wasn't sure exactly how to compare the userinput to the answer.